# How is my ubuntu startup program being invoked?

Tags: linux

I have created a startup program and forget how I did it and now I can't find it. I know the program is being executed because it runs and the TCP port is in use. If I change the port in the script and reboot, that port is now in use. My goal is to be able to turn off the program but since I can't find it I can't stop it from running.

I have tried...

```
"systemctl --user" - do not see program in list
"systemctl --user status <program name>" - this is how I had set it up at one time but this outputs Active: inactive (dead)
"lsof -i :8082" - it gave me the pid of the program using the port
"sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":8082"" - same as above
"sudo ps -fp <pid>" - this gave me the underlying program path (nodejs) and the folder containing the script (but not the script name strangely)
"sudo ls /etc/pam.d" - the program in question is not listed
"sudo cat /etc/rc.local" - file doesn't exist
"crontab -e" - not listed
"sudo ls /etc/init" - not listed
"sudo leafpad /etc/rc.local" - empty
"cat /etc/profile" - not listed
"cat ~./profile" - file doesn't exist
"cat ~/.bashrc" - not listed
"cat ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart" - empty
"sudo cd / && grep -R "router.js" - showed some useless lines eg. "grep: run/wpa_supplicant/wlp2s0: device or path doesn't exist"
"pstree" - didn't provide any useful info for my purposes
"pstree -H <pid>" - same as previous
"pstree <my user name>" - same as previous
```

Comment: You might get better answers on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl status` followed by the service name gives output like this

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-30 09:15:35 EDT; 1 day 5h ago
    Main PID: 711 (mysqld)
        Tasks: 31 (limit: 2319)
      CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
              └─711 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The "Loaded" script (`/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` above) is the path to the script that controls the service settings

Comment: You da man! You made me consider that this time I didn't install it as a --user service but a systemwide service. And there it was! Thanks!